# If Multiple inheritance has the diamond pattern issue, then Multiple Interfaces should also have the same issue

Tags: java

Java doesn't support multiple inheritance because if two classes have same function name but different implementation and if a third class inherits these two classes and if it wants to use the method, then it will create a confusion on which method should be called. So java uses multiple interfaces concept. But my doubt is if two multiple interfaces also have the same function name but different implementation and if a third class implements these two interfaces and when it provides implementation to that method then is it not a problem, please explain?

Comment: Interfaces provide no implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A clash between two interfaces occurs when two methods have the same parameters but a different return type.

Example:

```
public class MultipleInterfaceClash {

    public interface Foo {
        String baz(int a, String x);
    }

    public interface Bar {
        Double baz(int a, String x);
    }

    public class Confused implements Foo, Bar {

        // Compile error: The return type is incompatible with
        // MultipleInterfaceClash.Foo.baz(int, String)
        public Double baz(int a, String x) {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

It is not possible to implement both these interfaces.

Comment: +1. I suppose the same thing can happen when the `throws` clauses do not match.

Comment: or when generic type annotations conflict.

Answer (score 5):

Java interface only define the method name and have no implementation. The implementation of the methods is done in the class implementing the interface(s). Thus the problem is avoided.

Answer (score 3):

You do have this problem a little bit, if two interfaces provide methods with the same signature *that are supposed to do two different things*. Interfaces do not just specify a method signature, after all, but also a contract how they should be implemented (which a compiler cannot enforce, though). Then you cannot really extend both interfaces, because your implementation can only provide one method (so it has to choose one of the two contracts to fulfill). But of course, this is not a problem for the runtime system, but more of your interface design.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces have no implementation.

Only method definition

public Interface a{
       void a();
     }

Answer (score 0):

interface just provides a contract to the user, in this case the method signature.
The implementing classes must follow this contract. Hence, if two or more interfaces specify the same contract, then the implementing class do not have any issue as the implementation will serve the purpose.

Interfaces do not have any default implementation. Only method signature is specified.

Comment: OTOH, if the interfaces specify conflicting contracts, you cannot really implement both at the same time.

Comment: Exactly. The contract can not be conflicting. It either has to be same or completely different, may be an overloaded version.

Comment: It can be conflicting, if the methods with the same name and signature are specified to do different things. Also, I suppose the throws clauses could conflict, I wonder how the compiler handles this.

Comment: I meant .. should not be conflicting. Same conditions as there are for method overload.